# How can I know if an application uses RMI?

Tags: jakarta-ee, rmi

I am working on an existing Java EE Application. It was said that the application uses RMI calls for getting data for one of the modules.

I was searching for `UniCastRemoteObject` and `java.rmi.Remote`, but neither of those could be found in the project.

How can I tell if the application uses RMI or not? Is there any specific class that should be extended?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, there are many frameworks nowadays that "hide" explicit RMI code from you, 
So you will not find like this if RMI is used or not. 
I guess that if you know what "communication framework" you're using, you will know if the project uses RMI or not. 
For example, when I worked with [JBoss remoting](http://www.jboss.org/jbossremoting) I used an RMI "extension" to add RMI support without writing explicit RMI code, the framework did that to me. 
If you want to try and findout during runtime if application uses RMI, maybe should check if the process "[rmiregistry](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/rmi/running.html)" is up.

Comment: I thought about mentioning it, but I think that this is configurable, and I'm pretty sure I saw at least one application not using it. Thanks for the comment.